# VBA - Data validation with variable range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to set a data validation list from a variable range in another worksheet.  However, I am having trouble with the first bit of code to define the ranges.  Here is my code:-

```
Private Sub Workload_Schedule_Conditional_Formatting()

Dim LastRowWS As Long, LastRowPS As Long, rng As Range, ProjectRange As Range

    LastRowPS = Worksheets("Project_Summary").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ProjectRange = Worksheets("Project_Summary").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRowPS, 2))
    LastRowWS = Worksheets("Workload_Schedule").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Worksheets("Workload_Schedule").Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(LastRowWS, 7))

'Other code for validation list.

End Sub
```

I get an error on the `Set rng` line.  I can't figure out why this throws an error but the `Set ProjectRange` line doesn't (it is basically the exact same code but in a different worksheet).

Comment: You just need to fully qualify the `Cells` calls - they implicitly reference the `ActiveSheet`.  Also, snake case should be avoided in procedure names - the underscore has special meaning in VBA as an interface delimiter. I'd rename this `WorkloadScheduleConditionalFormatting`.

Comment: Thanks so much Comintem!  Would this be best done in With commands, or nominating the Worksheet before each Cell call?

Comment: I'd personally use `With` statements, but for 2 calls it really won't have that much performance impact to just use the worksheet references directly.

Comment: Thanks again!  Can you just help me out with the format of how to qualify the sheet reference for the cells.  I am assuming it would be something along the lines of Set ProjectRange = WSPS.Range(WSPS.Cells(2, 1), WSPS.Cells(LastRowPS, 2)) - where I have set WSPS as Worksheet and = Worksheets("Project_Summary").

Answer (score 0):

## With Readability

### Full

```
Sub Workload_Schedule_Conditional_Formatting()

    Dim LastRowWS As Long, LastRowPS As Long, rng As Range, _
            ProjectRange As Range

    With Worksheets("Project_Summary")
        LastRowPS = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set ProjectRange = .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRowPS, 2))
    End With
    With Worksheets("Workload_Schedule")
        LastRowWS = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(LastRowWS, 7))
    End With

    ' Other code for validation list.

End Sub
```

### Short

```
Sub Workload_Schedule_Conditional_Formatting_Short()

    Dim rng As Range, ProjectRange As Range

    With Worksheets("Project_Summary")
        Set ProjectRange = .Range(Cells(2, 1), _
                Cells(.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 2))
    End With
    With Worksheets("Workload_Schedule")
        Set rng = .Range(Cells(4, 3), _
                Cells(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 7))
    End With

    ' Other code for validation list.

End Sub
```